# Exploit Dom based XSS

Tags: security, xss, burp

While scanning burp suite has reported some tentative XSS(Dom-based); all stating the following,

The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based cross-site scripting. Data is read from window.location.hash and passed to `$()` via the following statement:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top }, 1000)
```

below is the response tab
[image]

Wondering what payload should I try to exploit it? or is it false positive?

Comment: Man. Did you figure this out? I tried recently with no luck either. Tried breaking out of the setTimeout function to place an alert but no luck.